# How to create a context for PHP fopen() to access an URL self-signed and required HTTP authorization?

Tags: php, ssl, authorization, fopen, self-signed

**I used fopen() in a home made function to access to an API. This API uses a self-signed cert and requires Authorization HTTP header to answer.**

Since migration from PHP ~5.3 to PHP 5.6, things changed. It was no longer possible to use my context (created via `stream_context_create()`) with my self signed certificate. I read a lot here about `verify_peer`, `verify_peer_name` and `allow_self_signed` options and it worked. Now I get a 401 error (instead of the `fopen()` error "Failed to enable crypto" I previously had).

More tests later, I realized I can't do both this self signed cert acceptation and give the `Authorization` header. I assume the previous option `verify_peer`, `verify_peer_name` and `allow_self_signed` are related to a `ssl` wrapper while the `Authorization` header only have meaning in a `http` wrapper. Is it true?

To create my `fopen()` context, I previously did that (I gave the `Authorization` header in my `$header parameter`) :

```
/**
 * Creation of a context for fopen the API
 * @param $method string HTTP Method wanted
 * @param $header array Associated array of addition header to put into the HTTP request
 * @param $content mixed Content of the request
 * @return resource Stream context for fopen
 */
function rest_context($method = 'GET', $header = null, $content = null)
{

    $http = array(
        'method' => mb_strtoupper($method),
        'ignore_errors' => true,
        'follow_location' => 0,
        'max_redirects' => 0
    );

    // Defaults header
    $header_arr = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );

    // Request content
    if (!is_null($content) && !empty($content))
    {
        if (is_array($content))
            $content = http_build_query($content);
        $http['content'] = $content;

        $header_arr['Content-Length'] = strlen($content);
    }

    // En-têtes
    if (!is_null($header) && !empty($header))
        $header_arr = array_merge($header_arr, $header);
    // rest_header_make creates headers well formated for the http request (array to string separeted with \n)
    $http['header'] = rest_header_make($header_arr);

    // Création et retour du contexte
    return stream_context_create(
        array('http' => $http)
    );
}
```

I tried the following solution to avoid the cert check but `Authorization` header seems ignored, I do not retrieve it when I look my API log. The changes are in the context options and in the name of the wrapper (`ssl` instead of `http`).

```
/**
 * Creation of a context for fopen the API
 * @param $method string HTTP Method wanted
 * @param $header array Associated array of addition header to put into the HTTP request
 * @param $content mixed Content of the request
 * @return resource Stream context for fopen
 */
function rest_context_new($method = 'GET', $header = null, $content = null)
{

    $http = array(
        'method' => mb_strtoupper($method),
        'ignore_errors' => true,
        'follow_location' => 0,
        'max_redirects' => 0,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    );

    // Defaults header
    $header_arr = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );

    // Request content
    if (!is_null($content) && !empty($content))
    {
        if (is_array($content))
            $content = http_build_query($content);
        $http['content'] = $content;

        $header_arr['Content-Length'] = strlen($content);
    }

    // En-têtes
    if (!is_null($header) && !empty($header))
        $header_arr = array_merge($header_arr, $header);
    // rest_header_make creates headers well formated for the http request (array to string separeted with \n)
    $http['header'] = rest_header_make($header_arr);

    // Création et retour du contexte
    return stream_context_create(
        array('ssl' => $http)
    );
}
```

Is there a way to give `Authorization` header with an API which used self signed certificate? How? Any clue is welcome ;) Thank you for your help.

Ak Tek